# Know if the record has been displayed 3 records and if so then put the another 3 records in a new line

Tags: php, html

Ok I have this code:

```
<?
$name=$_POST['name'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='$name'");
$ss = ""
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $ss .= "<div style='border:1px solid red; float:left; width:100px;'><img src="Images/media'.$row['name'].'" />";
    $ss .= "<p>".$row['title']."</p>";
    $ss .= "<p>".$row['description']."</p>";
    $ss .= "<a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['link']."</a></div>";

}

mysql_close($con);
?>

<? echo $ss; ?>
```

Now, I want to organize the display, therefore, I want the record to be set by 3 but the only problem where im stuck is I dont know how to make it to display in by set of 3. Im open for a suggestion, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a function

```
function sqlArr($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

a code

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("juliver");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$data = sqlArr("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='$name'");
$data = array_chunk($data,3);
include 'template.tpl.php';
```

a template

```
<table border='1'>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
<?   foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
    <td><?=$cell['id']?><?=$cell['title']?></td>
<?   endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but i get an error saying: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\madeinusa\cc.php on line 22'

and the line 22 is this: $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);.

Comment: you should have it in your code as well. what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: this is just an expirement but once this expirement is successful then I will implement this into my actual project.

Comment: well what is the purpose of this experiment? And are you sure you don't have the same error with your own code?

Comment: I am asking because the solution depends on the purpose.

Comment: Well, in the first place it should be $_GET, no POST (so, you have to use GET method or a hyperlink). And if there is a possibility for the name to be not set, check it with `isset()` function. `if (isset($_GET['name']))` create a query with name.

Answer (score 0):

In while loop you can put the condition to know when it executes 3 times then it would go automatically on other line. have a look

```
int $a=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        if($a%3==0){
    this will executes only if when the no of record dividable by 3. means 3,6,9,12..
                do this..
    }else {
     do this..
    }

    $a++;
    }
```

Comment: Just as a remark, you should initiate the $a outside the for, otherwise it will be always 0, and since 0 is dividable by 3 the code will be execute every time.